# How to have pattern and associated error messages in a list of dicts reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs...and trying to validate the input element for a particular pattern. I used the pattern attribute on input element to validate as below and it works.

```
validate = (event) => {
    let name = event.target.name;
    name = name.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, (letter) => {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
    if((event.target.value.length > 0  && this.state.has_focus) || 
    (event.target.value.length === 0 && this.state.has_focus)){
        if (!event.target.validity.valid) {
            if (event.target.validity.patternMismatch) {
                this.setState({is_valid: false});
                this.setState({error: 'Enter ' + name + ' matching the 
                pattern'});
            }
            if (event.target.validity.valueMissing) {
                this.setState({is_valid: false});
                this.setState({error: name + ' cannot be empty'});
            }
        }
        else {
            this.setState({is_valid: true});
        }
    }
};
input_change = (event) => {
    this.props.onChange(event);
    this.setState({text_input_value: event.target.value});
    this.validate(event);
};

<Input name="name" placeholder="Type a name here" required value= 
{this.state.name} onChange={this.input_change}
                            disabled={disabled}
                            pattern="^[a-z]$"/>
```

Instead of this i would like to have pattern and its associated error messages in a list of dicts (to start with input length limiting to 10 characters being the pattern) and in the future can add more patterns. How can i go about with this. Thanks.